# trying to run a python script on AWS Lambda, but Lambda fails if I load a virtualenv directory

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've got a script working running on AWS Lambda that will run a python script, however I need boto installed, so I have created a virtualenv.

However if I pass the env/* directories to Lambda, it just fails with a system error.

I have ziped and passed the directory and then just done an ls to see if its there, but it still fails. Somehow Lambda is unhappy with the env/* directory, either size or some rule, not sure. Its not the python script failing, just loading the env/* causes the failure.

Can anyone tell me why, or how to get around it

Thanks

Marc Nealer

Comment: Folks could help you more if you provided more details about exactly what you did and what failure you experienced.

Comment: Bascially, I created a virtualenv file set and used pip into install Boto. I then pass over a simple index.js file that will just do an 'ls' command via a child proccess. If I zip the index,js file on its own or with other files, it works fine. However if I zip the env directories, Lambda just says 'system error' No log, no details

Answer (score 1):

Marc

You want to zip up only the following items when loading into Lambda

- /env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
- Your python script

You can refer to Amazon's instructions below, which I successfully followed this morning. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

P.S. boto3 already comes pre-packaged in AWS Lambda, so if that's all you need, you can simply call it via an import in your python script.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to how to get around it, [nstack](https://nstack.com/) allows you to run Python directly and with OS / pip dependencies (as you can run JavaScript on Lambda).

Full disclosure: I am one of the founders.